# Is using MaterializeCss (jQuery based) with ReactJs bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, materialize

[MaterializeCss](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) is a great css framework and currently relies on jQuery. [Material-ui](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/) is the most popular ReactJs version of this.

I want to use (and learn) ReactJs and build an app with MaterializeCss (see why below).  There is the [react-materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/) library, but it uses jQuery.

Isn't using ReactJs and jQuery bad practice? If so, does this mean I should just stick to jQuery if I want to use MaterializeCss?

Some other points:

- I want to use MaterializeCss because I don't think material-ui is as pretty and it's performance/animations just seems so laggy and slow (even in the new version).
- The team at MaterializeCss plan on moving away from jQuery eventually.
- Javascript fatigue creeping in here big time and I haven't even started!